# Call a method from a Groovy map transformed to a class with asType

Tags: methods, groovy, interface, closures

Is it possible to call methodTwo() as in

```
def map = [methodOne: { return "${methodTwo()}" }, methodTwo: { return "Hey" }] as MyInterface
```

methodTwo cannot be found at runtime by groovy (it seems that it is searching its definition inside the class where the map was defined)

Comment: Post `MyInterface` code and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the method declaring the `map` variable before, and then referencing it:

```
interface MyInterface {
    def methodOne()
    def methodTwo()
}

def map
map = [
    methodOne: { return "${map.methodTwo()}" }, 
    methodTwo: { return "Hey" }
] as MyInterface

assert map.methodOne() == "Hey"
```